# How do you make page numbers in Google Docs?

Tags: creative-writing, formatting, book, google-docs

I really need to know how to make the page numbers in Google Docs look like a real book. I know how to do the page numbers, but how do you do them half on the right side and half on the left (like an actual book has them so that the pages on the don't have a page number in the crease of the book)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software use, not writing.

Comment: While it could be argued that this is on-topic here, I think it would get better answers and be better maintained on Superuser.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it is on topic now and I would like to see it reopened (+1 reopen vote from me).

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to address this problem before, and I double-checked both Google help files and Google Add-Ons in hope of finding a solution for you (and me), but I've had no luck.

Google Docs does not distinguish between odd and even pages that, in a book, would become the recto and verso pages. Without recto and verso, one cannot place a gutter margin on the page (as usually required by printers) or position the page number on the upper outside corner.

I hoped that some add-on might retrofit the odd/even distinction onto a document, but I found nothing that would help.

I wonder if you might find some sort of PDF file editor that would do this for you: you'd download your Google Doc as a PDF then feed it to the converter which would add a gutter margin and the page numbers in the appropriate places. It isn't uncommon to see physical books represented electronically as PDF files before they go to press, so this seems to be the next best place to look.

I'm sorry I don't have better news for you.

Comment: Considering specific needs like the odd/even distinction for numbering pages, you seem to have a serious use of your tools.
Wouldn't be a serious program, like LaTeX be a better approach then ?
(I came here because Google doc doesn't even seem capable of numbering the pages with their total number, i.e. "1/2" & "2/2", rather than simple "1" & "2".  Simple of use... but so limited !)